# How do you decimate a photogrammetry model so it compresses the textures like

Tags: texturing, modifiers

Hi how would you reduce both the geometry And the texture of a photogrammetry model such that the texture is compressed like such:[image]

I can use the decimate but it keeps the original photo detail. In the above example was the photo courted to something like vertex colors?

Is this possible in Blender? Or should I try MeshLab?

Thanks!!

~be

Comment: Same or similar effect for a different use case here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28981/solid-color-for-each-face-in-cycles-when-using-image-textures

Comment: Thanks @numanair, I'll check it out