# Cycles nodes: is there a way to find coordinates change, derivative, direction?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, procedural

I want to get a unique random value for every face using direction of mesh coordinates. Like a derivative, position change, a unit vector based on current face's vertices. (I guess, something similar to `dFdx()` in OpenGL.)

I tried to find the answer on Google, but got no results, though as a software developer I think this function isn't difficult to create. Maybe some Blender experts here know the solution?

Comment: Bake world position to a texture image, then do a two lookups on that texture, one at a UV offset, to get ddx(UV)/ddx(worldpos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not *strictly* an answer to your question, but..

To get a random value per face to be read by Cycles, you could use an adaptation
of Chebhou's answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34668/use-id-properties-in-cycles-nodes).

Run this script on the active object:

```
import bpy
import random

obj = bpy.context.object
obj_data = obj.data
group_name = 'face_ID'

#check for existing group with the same name
if None == obj_data.vertex_colors.get(group_name): 
    obj_data.vertex_colors.new(name=group_name)
color_map =  obj_data.vertex_colors[group_name]

for poly in obj_data.polygons:
    rnd=random.random()
    color = (rnd, rnd, rnd,0)
    for loop_ind in poly.loop_indices:
        color_map.data[loop_ind].color = color
```

and then use the Cycles 'Attribute' node to retrieve the generated vertex color layer by name:

[image]

result of this example on a subdivided plane:

[image]

I've moved the randomization into the script - I was having trouble getting a good pseudo-random number out of  a 0.0-1.0 input range using nodes. If nobody points out something obvious in a comment, I'll post that as another question.

Comment: I haven't yet worked with Python scripts in Blender, but will start it with your code :) But my answer (use normals) is closer to geometry, and I will use it if won't find an answer to [my other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/114079/51657). And thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that I can use normal to achieve almost the same behaviour – it is perpendicular to the direction of a face, so, it is an almost isomorphic value that gives some unique value for a face. But I will appreciate any better answer.