# How to create a gradient along the edge of an object procedurally?

Tags: texturing, procedural

I wanted a gradient effect along the edge of an object procedurally made, so that I could add two different colors, gradient used as a factor.

I don't know how the original was made, but I think I am going to use the scalable vector graph to make the maps. The topology may be in ngon. lastly I would like to render in EEVEE.

[image]

Comment: We need more details, how the generated object looks in regards to topology. In general, tricky subject; maybe this helps: [Cycles nodes: is it possible to get distance to nearest edge?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/114079/60486)

Comment: If you're looking for this exact effect, you could fake it using Ambient occlusion and using different heights for your objects. Do you want to use eevee or cycles ?

Comment: The link given by @MarkusvonBroady creates what you want. The only thing you have to know is that to get the desired effect, the objects that make the country cannot be flat planes, you have to extrude them so that they have a thickness. Otherwise there is no edge for the Bevel node.