# Distance to nearest edge in a shader

Tags: texturing, shaders, procedural

I made a procedural polka dot shader. It's applied to a flat n-gon, rounded via subdiv surface modifier.

[image]

**I'd like to eliminate all dots that are not fully contained inside n-gon edges**. To do this the shader would need to determine the distance from a tile center to the nearest edge. Is there a way or some trickery to query this?

I looked into existing posts regarding similar problems, namely [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114079/cycles-nodes-is-it-possible-to-get-distance-to-nearest-edge) and [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267087/procedural-border-detection-on-a-flat-object/267109) but still can't get wanted results. Seems that output of nodes that rely on sampling (ao or bevel) can't be properly threshold-ed for shader to determine if a position is far enough from an edge. For example the ao shader output connected via "less than" node will still produce a falloff, as seen on the image below.

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!