# Material colors of faces set to specific random ones by node editor

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, faces, color

I figured out so far to make different objects with the same material and a color ramp in the nodes editor be chosen to have one of those colors somewhere in the ramp sceme. 
When I now got for example objects that contain lots and lots of leaves; how can I make (for the start, I will later have to define it so that connected faces will have the same, though) each face being used as well for exactly that material choice? 
 I would need something to tell the nodes that I want the faces to be changed instead of the whole material. 
Possible? 
Not? 
Any other solutions that would give compareable results?
Thanks for helping me. 
*(If needed, I'll give a screenshot of my current nodes, though they are messy because I also made the alpha value be set by the shadow and distance of the light source to a different amount -cough-)*

Comment: I'm not clear on the question. Is this what you are after: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35273/how-to-make-ivys-leaves-colored-randomly/35274#35274 ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you’re trying to get each *face* to be randomly assigned a consistent colour. Something like this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80299/29586 should help - it, generate the UV with each face assigned to a single point. A random texture should then give each face a random solid color.

Comment: -> connected faces having the same actually. There are leaves from sapling generator addon that I want to behave this way.