# How to color individual polygons in a low poly model?

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, materials, uv

So I have been working on this low poly project and have most of the modeling done. So, I have begun texturing and ran into a problem. I can't figure out how to color each individual polygon of my model. Here let me explain.

[image]

Notice how this image(that I found in a google search) has polygons in the model and it transition from blue to red and even in the blue and red the saturation and brightness changes to achieve a more natural look. Now I understand this effect can be achieved with lighting, but I'm doing a landscape so one solid color will not look good. I'm looking for natural variations in color and can't figure how to color them individually.

Comment: Do you want to achieve the same effect like in [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27747/is-there-a-smart-way-to-apply-a-better-transition-between-colours-while-maintain) ?

Comment: Yes or something similar.

Comment: Then I think you have possibility to get desired result using ways from 2 answers in the linked thread - either by code provided or extruding and deleting original geometry (to detach faces from each other). Just don't remove doubles if using 2-nd way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like it was done using vertex colors.

Go into Vertex Paint mode and apply your colors.  Note that faces will blend colors in a gradient based on their vertices' colors.

Then, in your Blender Render material, select the Vertex Color Paint option.

[image]